# appropriate moment to remove controller from navigation stack

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a very simple situation: I have three UIViewControllers, A, B, C.
A opens B, B opens C. Now, from controller C, on back, application should go to controller A, not B. What is the right way to achieve this?

1) Make custom back button on controller C, make its "`back`" method and in it pop to controller A?
2) Go through an array of controllers obtained from navigation controller and remove controller B? Do this in `viewDidLoad` of controller C?
3) Go through an array of controllers obtained from navigation controller and remove controller B and o this in `viewWillDisappear` of controller B?

Comment: i'm sure it's first one

Comment: Yes the first one should be your choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pop all viewcontroller to the root viewcontroller, you can use `popToRootViewControllerAnimated`

```
[navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Set animation to YES/NO depending on your needs whether you want animation or not.

You can put this code on back button click.

Comment: Yes, but I have to "emulate" the back button in that case

Comment: @Maggie You need to, there is not any other way to do that.

Comment: In that case, controller B still remains on the stack, right? So, the next time I try to access it, its viewDidLoad method won't get called? Just viewWillAppear. Am I right?

Comment: @Maggie No, controller B will be pulled from the stack automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom back button on controller C and write its back event as:

```
-(IBAction)backButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
}
```

Seeing your view hierarchy I am sure it will pop to controller A.

Comment: Not the right way to pop the controllers like this. Why don't you use popToRootViewControllerAnimated instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

On Back button selector method, Pop to root View controller of Navigation Controller.

```
-(void)backBtnAction:(id)sender
{
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```